# Rendering bug with overlapping text

Tags: bug, status-norepro

**Edit:** *whatever was done for the new design apparently also solved this problem. At least since this morning I have not been able to replicate the problem. Thanks to all who chimed in.*

I sometimes run into this weird rendering bug where text is displayed as overlapped. See picture below. I think I only see this on math.SE, and not on, say, tex.SE, so I suspect it may have to do with MatJax?

[image: screenshot]

The system on which I see this bug runs Scientific Linux with Firefox 3.6.11. Is it just me, or do other people see this artifact?

(Ha! How apropos, as I type this the preview window also shows the same sort of the rendering problem.)

Comment: @Willie Does this happen to you on Chrome?

Comment: @Willie: I inserted the screenshot for you.

Comment: @Willie: Does it happen on (1) http://mathoverflow.net and (2) http://www.mathjax.org/?

Comment: @Jin and @KennyTM: I will test tomorrow. This doesn't happen on my laptop, only on my office computer. I don't recall it ever happening on MathOverflow (I probably would've noticed if it did). I wouldn't be surprised that it has sometime to do with the way my office computer is set up (which is out of my control).

Comment: Oh wait, @Jin, I cannot test Chrome, since I have no software installation privileges. But I will try to test on Opera or Konqueror; I know at least one of the two is installed on my office box.